# javascript call instantiated class

Tags: javascript

Is there a way that I can make a class that is callable? I.e. I want to do:

```
var a = new callable();

a(1,2,3);

a.property = 5;

console.log(a.property+1); // 6
```

==================Context=============
I'm trying to make a function preload interceptor, which works like this:

1. you can call the function `wrapper.f_shadow()`, and `wrapper.f_shadow()` will cache all calls towards it
2. later, when `f_real` is ready, it will take all the cached calls from `f_shadow` and execute them.

My idea currently is to create a `class f_shadow` with a call method, so I can do something like:

```
wrapper.f = new f_shadow();

wrapper.f(args1);
wrapper.f(args2);
wrapper.f(args3);

f_real = ()=>{do_stuff();};

replace(wrapper.f, f_real);
```

Comment: Return a function? `function Foo() {return () => console.log('foo');}`, and then use `const a = new Foo(); a();`. Only question is why you want to use `new` and not a regular function such as `const foo = () => () => console.log('x');` and then use `const a = foo(); a();`

Comment: Ah fair. I should probably specify that I also want to keep some properties within `a = new callable()`; so that I can `a.cachedCalls` later. Will edit question.

Comment: function are objects, so you can add properties to them just like you can with regular objects, for example `fn.x = 1`, and then return `fn`. Here is one example using object.assign: `const foo = () => Object.assign(() => console.log('foo'), {x: 1});`, then you can use `const a = foo(); a(); console.log(a.x);`. I don't think using `new`/classes are the corrrect tool here, since you want the return value to be a function

Comment: eg: something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pxube2Ls/) would work, but since you're just using the constructor to return a function, you might as well use a [regular function](https://jsfiddle.net/pxube2Ls/1/) at that point

Comment: Thanks! That would do it. I was just not fully comfortable with the functions-are-objects-too thing. :D

Comment: Ok never mind, that won't do. I need the function to be able to modify its own properties (in the same way one might use `this` in a function); and I want to easily be able to spawn copies of this - so i think a class would be better here.

Comment: hm, I'm not too sure I fully understand your question. But maybe you're after something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vke239Ls/1/) that uses a class to store the arguments passed into the function `f` and then allows you to access those functions in `ready()`. Alternatively, you can achieve the same with a [functional appraoch](https://jsfiddle.net/vke239Ls/3/) instaed with closures

Answer (score 0):

Long ago (well, not that long: before 2015) Javascript didn't have *literal* classes.  Instead, every class was instead created as a function.

Even today, the `class` keyword is 99% syntactic sugar on top of that functional base, so really all you need to do is:

```
const A = function(...args) {
   this.property = 5;
}
```

Of course, that will create separate copies of objects (including arrays and functions) for each instance.  If you want all of your instances to share a function (to create a method), you simply assign it to the `prototype` property of the class/function:

```
A.prototype.logProperty = function() {
    console.log(this.property);
}

const a = new ();
a.logProperty(); // logs 5
```

But of course, any "class function" that you use will still be a regular function, and it can still return values when used normally (those returned values won't be used by the class however).

Comment: Thanks! Yes I get this, but it wasn't quite what I was going for, since I want a() to be callable straight off the bat instead of a.something(). Imean, a.something works, but i was just wondering about this syntax specifically.

Comment: I literally provided what you asked for: "a way that I can make a class that is callable".

Comment: You've given me a class with a property that is callable. The class is not callable.

Comment: If you re-read my answer... "But of course, any "class function" that you use will still be a regular function, and it can still return values when used normally" ... in other words, it is still just a regular function (even though it can be used as a class), and as such it *is* callable.

Comment: Ok, so you've given me a class-constructor that is callable as a regular function. I wanted a class INSTANCE that is callable as a function. my bad for not being clear

Comment: Whenever you have a new *actual* question, you should use a new *Stack Overflow* question to ask it, rather than trying to repurpose an existing question.

Comment: This is the intent of the original question. I've done enough JS to know that a class constructor can be called as a regular function. I would like help with a callable class please.

Comment: In my question I clearly have `a = new callable(); a()` not `a=new callable(); b=callable();`

Comment: After reviewing various posts about the js equivalent of the python __call__() function, where I originally got my idea from, it seems that this is Just Not Something We Do in Javascript; which is fair enough. Thanks for your diligence anyways.

Comment: Again, you *can* do `a = new callable()` **OR** you *can* do `callable()` ... **OR** you *can* even do `a = callable()` ... all with the exact same function. 
 When you use it with the `new` keyword, the function acts like a class (ie. `a` becomes the `this` object built inside the function) ... whereas when you don't use it with `new`, `a` simply becomes the function's return value.  Thus, any function designed to be used both ways (both with `this` and with `return`) *is* a "callable class".